# Imprimir documento na impressora sem interação do usuário

Tags: php, javascript, navegador-de-internet

Preciso imprimir um documento enviando diretamente para a impressora sem o usuário precisar escolher a impressora. Como faço isso com `PHP5` ou `JavaScript`?

Verifiquei que com `JavaScript` tem a possibilidade de fazer com `window.print`, mas daí abre a tela de impressão para selecionar a impressora, que não é o que eu quero.

Comment: A aplicação roda na mesma rede que a impressora?

Comment: Dependendo da impressora, pode tentar uma solução mais elaborada com o Google Cloud Print.
Depende do suporte da impressora, https://github.com/yasirsiddiqui/php-google-cloud-print

Comment: Caso de ser na mesma rede e tiver conhecimentos sobre CUPS (servidor de impressão nativo no linux), pode tentar configurar o CUPS e mandar as requisições diretamente para ele. http://www.nongnu.org/phpprintipp/

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível utilizando apenas Javascript e PHP.

No Firefox, existe uma configuração para sempre imprimir quando invocado o método window.print().
- Acesse about:config
- Crie uma nova preferência do tipo booleano com o nome de print.always_print_silent e marque-a como true.

Após reiniciar o navegador, qualquer chamada via Javascript com código window.print() iniciará a impressão automaticamente.

Lembrando que esta preferência valerá para qualquer site que invocar o referido método.